# How to Decode MD5 String in Android?

Tags: java, android, md5, decode, encode

I am using this code for encoding MD5. Please tell me how to decode this.

```
public static final String md5(final String toEncrypt) {
    try {
        final MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("md5");
        digest.update(toEncrypt.getBytes());
        final byte[] bytes = digest.digest();
        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
            sb.append(String.format("%02X", bytes[i]));
        }
        return sb.toString().toLowerCase();
    } catch (Exception exc) {
        return ""; // Impossibru!
    }
}
```

Comment: MD5 isn't an "encoding", and you can't "decode" it. Learn about **one-way** hashes.

Comment: MD5 is single entry point we can't decrypt it.

Comment: Updated Wikipedia page to reflest that MD5 is a one-way function, it is neither encryption nor encoding. It can not be reversed other than a brute force attack.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. MD5 is no encryption algorithm, it's an hashing algorithm, meaning that you can revert it back to the original string. Actually, as the collision risk on this is not that low, there are even multiple source strings that would correspond to the same MD5 hash.

Comment: any other solution for encryption and decryption of string?

Comment: Plenty. Just google it...

Comment: @LaurentS. Google bringing us here :(